# ¿En qué está fallando mi responsive dropdown menú?

Tags: javascript, scss, dropdown

## Antes que nada, ¡muy buen día!

Hace unos días consulté sobre unos problemas que tenía sobre mi dropdown menú en versión desktop y por suerte pude solucionarlo, ahora el problema sucede en versiones menores a 1022px...

### Esto funciona así con respecto al sub-menú... (y esto no es un problema XD)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar es sencillo... le haces click y a partir de una función de JS más algunos keyframes y propiedades de CSS cambia las categorías por sub-menús

### Y cuando agrego funciones al trigger y al close funciona de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo perfecto... ¿no?

### **Pero... el problema**

Cuando en **CSS** agrego la propiedad "transform: translateX(-100%)" al contenedor de mi nav para que no sea visible, la **función javascript** que hace aparecerlo con la clase .active anula la **otra función** que permite la aparición de los sub-menú de cada categoría. Básicamente, solo se valida la función de apertura y cierre del menú pero no la apertura y cierre de las subcategorías (que por defecto son todas las mismas en el HTML, siempre aparecen After Effects, Premiere, etc...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### ¿Qué estoy buscando?

Creo que es evidente lo que necesito... que una función no anule la otra, que pueda abrir y cerrar el menú y al hacer click sobre las categorías se abran los sub-menú correspondientes de c/u

### Código

#### HTML

```
<header class="encabezado header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row v-center">
            <!-- Logotipo -->
            <div class="logo header-item item-left">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="assets/logos/dvz-color.png" alt="dvz-logo"></a>
            </div>
            <!-- Menú -->
            <div class="nav header-item item-center">
                <div class="menu-overlay"></div> 
                <nav class="menu" id="menu">
                    <div class="mobile-menu-head" id="mobile">
                        <div class="go-back">
                            <i class='bx bx-left-arrow-alt'></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="current-menu_title">
                            <img src="assets/logos/dvz-color.png" alt="dvz-color">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mobile-menu-close" id="close">
                            <i class='bx bx-x'></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="menu-main" id="menuMain">
                        <li class="nav-item item-father menu-item-has-children">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Edición de video <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i></a>
                            <div class="sub-menu mega-menu single-column-menu" id="subMenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere-pro">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos//davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                                        <a href="#">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="wondershare-filmora">
                                        <a href="#">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item-father menu-item-has-children">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Edición de audio <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i></a>
                            <div class="sub-menu mega-menu single-column-menu" id="subMenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere-pro">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos//davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                                        <a href="#">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="wondershare-filmora">
                                        <a href="#">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item-father menu-item-has-children">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Diseño Gráfico <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i></a>
                            <div class="sub-menu mega-menu single-column-menu" id="subMenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere-pro">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos//davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                                        <a href="#">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="wondershare-filmora">
                                        <a href="#">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item item-father menu-item-has-children">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">Desarrollo Web <i class='bx bx-chevron-down'></i></a>
                            <div class="sub-menu mega-menu single-column-menu" id="subMenu">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/after-effects.png" alt="after-effects">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe After Effects</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/premiere.png" alt="premiere-pro">
                                        <a href="#">Adobe Premiere Pro</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos//davinci-resolve.png" alt="davinci-resolve">
                                        <a href="#">Da Vinci Resolve</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <img src="assets/iconos/filmora.png" alt="wondershare-filmora">
                                        <a href="#">Wondershare Filmora</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <div class="img">
                            <img src="assets/logos/dvz-color.png" alt="dvz-color">
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <!-- Usuarios -->
            <div class="users header-item item-right">
                <i class='bx bx-cart'></i>
                <i class='bx bxs-user-circle'></i>
                <label class="mobile-menu-trigger">
                    <span></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

#### Fragmento CSS (Sass)

```
        .nav {
            @include mQuerie(m) {
                // order: 3;
                // flex: 0 0 100%;
                // position: fixed;
                // width: 32px;
                // background-color: #ffffff;
                // box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #ccc;
                // left: 0;
                // top: 0;
                // height: 100%;
                // width: 350px;
                // display: block;
            }

            .menu-overlay {

                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    position: fixed;
                    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100%;
                    z-index: 1098;
                    visibility: hidden;
                    opacity: 0;
                    transition: all 0.5s ease;
                }

                &.active {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            .menu {
                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    position: fixed;
                    width: 360px;
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    left: 0;
                    top: 0;
                    height: 100%;
                    transition: all 0.5s ease;
                    z-index: 1100;
                    transform: translateX(-100%);

                    &.active {
                        transform: translateX(0%);
                    }
                }

                .mobile-menu-head {
                    display: none;

                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                        display: flex;
                        height: 60px;
                        border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                        justify-content: space-between;
                        align-items: center;
                        position: relative;
                        z-index: 9999;
                        position: static;
                        background-color: #ffffff;
                        top: 0;

                        &.active {
                            .go-back {
                                display: block;
                            }
                            .current-menu_title{
                                visibility: visible;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .go-back {
                        height: 60px;
                        width: 60px;
                        border-right: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                        cursor: pointer;
                        line-height: 60px;
                        text-align: center;
                        color: #000000;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        display: none;

                        i {
                            font-size: 50px;
                            padding: 5px 0px;
                        }
                    }

                    .current-menu_title {
                        display: flex;
                        flex-direction: row;
                        justify-content: center;
                        align-items: center;
                        font-size: 20px;
                        font-weight: 500;
                        color: #000000;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        img{
                            width: 45px;
                            height: 45px;
                        }
                    }

                    .mobile-menu-close {
                        height: 60px;
                        width: 60px;
                        border-left: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                        cursor: pointer;
                        line-height: 60px;
                        text-align: center;
                        color: #000000;

                        i {
                            font-size: 50px;
                            padding: 5px 0px;
                        }
                    }

                }

                .menu-main {
                    /* Categorías UL */
                    display: flex;

                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                        height: 100%;
                        overflow-x: hidden;
                        overflow-y: auto;
                        flex-direction: column;
                    }

                    .nav-item {
                        /* Categorías LI */
                        padding: 25px 0px;

                        @include mQuerie(m) {
                            line-height: 1;
                            margin: 0;
                            padding: 0;
                            display: block;
                        }

                        .nav-link {
                            /* Categorías Anchor */
                            font-family: 'Roboto Flex', sans-serif;
                            font-size: 1.7rem;
                            font-weight: 600;
                            padding: 0px 10px;
                            color: black;

                            &:hover {
                                i {
                                    transition: .3s;
                                    transform: rotate(180deg);
                                }
                            }

                            i {
                                font-size: 1.5rem;

                                @include mQuerie(m) {
                                    position: absolute;
                                    right: 0;
                                    padding: 0px 14.5px;
                                    border-left: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                                    height: 50px;
                                    line-height: 50px;
                                    font-size: 3rem;
                                }
                            }

                            &:hover {
                                color: $principal;
                            }

                            @include mQuerie(m) {
                                position: relative;
                                left: -40px;
                                top: 0px;
                                line-height: 50px;
                                height: 50px;
                                width: 360px;
                                padding: 0 50px 0 15px;
                                display: block;
                                border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
                                
                            }

                        }

                        .sub-menu {
                            /* Subcategorías DIV */
                            /* Caja contenedora del dropdown menú*/
                            position: absolute;
                            z-index: 500;
                            background-color: rgba(116, 116, 116, .7);
                            box-shadow: -2px 2px 70px -25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
                            padding: 20px 30px;
                            transition: all 0.5s ease;
                            top: 80px;
                            left: 0;
                            right: 0;
                            opacity: 0;
                            visibility: hidden;
                            @include mQuerie(m){
                                background-color: white;
                                visibility: visible;
                                opacity: 1;
                                position: absolute;
                                box-shadow: none;
                                margin: 0;
                                padding: 15px;
                                top: 60px;
                                width: 100%;
                                height: 100%;
                                display: none;
                                transform: translateX(0%);
                                overflow-y: auto;


                                &.active{
                                    display: block;
                                }

                                @keyframes slideLeft {
                                    0% {
                                        opacity: 0;
                                        transform: translateY(100%);
                                    }

                                    100% {
                                        opacity: 1;
                                        transform: translateY(0%);
                                    }
                                }
    
                                @keyframes slideRight {
                                    0% {
                                        opacity: 1;
                                        transform: translateY(0%);
                                    }
    
                                    100% {
                                        opacity: 0;
                                        transform: translateY(100%);
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            ul {
                                /* Disposición de elementos del dropdown menú */
                                display: flex;
                                flex-direction: row;
                                justify-content: center;
                                align-items: center;
                                @include mQuerie(m){
                                    width: 360px;
                                    position: absolute;
                                    top: 0;
                                    left: 0;
                                    flex-direction: column;
                                }
                            }

                            li {
                                /* Elementos individuales del dropdown menú*/
                                align-self: flex-start;
                                font-size: 1.7rem;
                                display: flex;
                                justify-content: center;
                                align-items: center;
                                padding: 20px;

                                @include mQuerie(m){
                                    width: 360px;
                                    position: relative;
                                    left: -40px;
                                    justify-content: flex-start;
                                    border-bottom: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
                                }

                                a {
                                    font-size: 1.5rem;
                                    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

                                    @include mQuerie(m) {
                                        color: black;
                                    }

                                    &:hover {
                                        color: rgb(232, 204, 133);
                                    }

                                }

                                img {
                                    width: 32px;
                                    height: 32px;
                                    margin-right: 10px;
                                    border-radius: 50%;
                                }

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    .img{
                        display: none;
                        @include mQuerie(m){
                            display: block;
                            width: 360px;
                            position: relative;
                            left: -40px;
                            margin: 40px 0px;
                            img{
                                width: 100px;
                                height: 100px;
                                margin: 0px 130px;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    .item-father:hover {
                        .sub-menu {
                            visibility: visible;
                            opacity: 1;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        .users {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;

            @include mQuerie(m) {
                flex: 0 0 auto;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .bx-cart {
                padding: 0px 15px;
            }

            .bx-menu {
                margin-left: 15px;
                display: none;

                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    display: block;
                    margin-left: 0;
                }
            }

            .bxs-user-circle {
                @include mQuerie(m) {
                    display: none;
                }
            }

            .mobile-menu-trigger {
                display: flex;
                height: 30px;
                width: 30px;
                margin-left: 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;

                span {
                    display: block;
                    height: 2px;
                    background-color: #333333;
                    width: 24px;
                    position: relative;

                    &:before {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        background-color: #333333;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        content: '';
                        position: absolute;
                        left: 0;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 100%;
                        background-color: #333333;
                    }

                    &:before {
                        top: -6px;
                    }

                    &:after {
                        top: 6px;
                    }
                }

            }

            i {
                font-size: 3.5rem;
                cursor: pointer;

                &:hover {
                    color: $principal;
                }
            }
        }
```

#### JavaScript

```
const menu = document.getElementById("menu");
const menuMain = document.getElementById("menuMain");
const goBack = document.querySelector(".go-back");
const menuTrigger = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-trigger");
const closeMenu = document.querySelector(".mobile-menu-close");
let subMenu;

menuMain.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
        return;
    }
    if (e.target.closest(".menu-item-has-children")) {
        const hasChildren = e.target.closest(".menu-item-has-children");
        showSubMenu(hasChildren);
    }
});

goBack.addEventListener("click", () => {
    hideSubMenu();
})

menuTrigger.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggleMenu();
})

closeMenu.addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggleMenu();
})

document.querySelector(".menu-overlay").addEventListener("click", () => {
    toggleMenu();
})

function toggleMenu() {
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
    document.querySelector(".menu-overlay").classList.toggle("active");
}

function showSubMenu(hasChildren) {
    subMenu = hasChildren.querySelector(".sub-menu");
    subMenu.classList.add("active");
    subMenu.style.animation = "slideLeft 0.5s ease forwards";
    const menuTitle = hasChildren.querySelector("i").parentNode.childNodes[0].textContent;
    menu.getElementsByClassName(".current-menu-title").innerHTML = menuTitle;
    console.log(menuTitle)
    menu.querySelector(".mobile-menu-head").classList.add("active");
}

function hideSubMenu() {
    subMenu.style.animation = "slideRight 0.5s ease forwards";
    setTimeout(() => {
        subMenu.classList.remove("active");
    }, 300);
    menu.getElementsByClassName(".current-menu-title").innerHTML = "";
    menu.querySelector(".mobile-menu-head").classList.remove("active");
}

window.onresize = function () {
    if (this.innerWidth > 1022) {
        if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
            toggleMenu();
        }

    }
}
```

#### Link al repositorio de GitHub

https://github.com/tomdvazq/dvz-eCommerce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## ¡Auto respuesta!

Al parecer estar incluyendo la clase .active vía **JavaScript** a todos mis elementos estaba generando algún conflicto de CSS y por ende no podían relacionarse entre sí.

### La solución

En la función que abre y cierra el menú de navegación en vista mobile cambié la clase .active por una nueva y específica para ello que fue .open

```
//ANTES//

function toggleMenu() {
    menu.classList.toggle("active");
    document.querySelector(".menu-overlay").classList.toggle("active");
}

//DESPUÉS//

function toggleMenu() {
    menu.classList.toggle("open");
    document.querySelector(".menu-overlay").classList.toggle("open");
}
```

Al código CSS (Sass) modifiqué el nombre de la clase menu**.active** por menu**.open**, lo mismo realicé con la clase .menu-overlay.**active** renombrándola a .menu-overlay.**open**

```
        .menu {
            @include mQuerie(m) {
                position: fixed;
                width: 360px;
                background-color: #ffffff;
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                height: 100%;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
                z-index: 1100;
                transform: translateX(-150%);

                &.open {
                    transform: translateX(0%);
                }
            }

        .menu-overlay {

            @include mQuerie(m) {
                position: fixed;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
                left: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 1098;
                visibility: hidden;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: all 0.5s ease;
            }
                &.open {
                    visibility: visible;
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Qué bueno que ya encontraste solución. No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.